# as_json not including association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am trying to override the `as_json` method in my `Edge` class so I can include the  `x` and `y` coordinates of it's from and to `Vertex`.

The assosiations are like this:

`Edge belongs_to :from` and `:to` Vertex.

`Vertex has_many :edges`, where `:x` and `:y` are fields.

I have tried several syntactic variation, like the one below, but can't get it to work. Thanks for any help!

```
def as_json(options={})
  super only: [:name, :value, :color], include: [
                                  { from: { only: [:x, :y] } },
                                  {   to: { only: [:x, :y] } } 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the following:

```
super only: [:name, :value, :color],
        include: {
          from: { only: [:x, :y] },
          to: { only: [:x, :y] }
        }
```

Comment: Ah, then I had it earlier. Got thrown of because of a `undefined method 'serializable_hash'` exception. Next goal will be solving that one, so I guess my question is invalid.